# Aggettivo o espressione per qualificare qualcuno con delle fissazioni capricciose

Tags: translation, word-choice, adjectives, phrase-request

In catalano si usa l'aggettivo "maniàtic" e in
castigliano "maniático" (che non significa lo stesso che "maníaco") per descrivere una persona che ha delle fissazioni capricciose e a volte persino stravaganti
(perché queste fissazioni si chiamano "manías", quindi una persona "maniática" è qualcuno che ha molte "manías"). Si tratta di una caratteristica che si può trovare con certa frequenza in persone anziane, per esempio.

L'aggettivo è usato di solito con una connotazione piuttosto negativa ed è prossimo agli aggettivi inglesi [fussy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fussy) e  [finicky](https://www.lexico.com/definition/finicky?language_pair=es-en&locale=en). Per esempio, si potrebbe dire

> Es una vieja maniática

e certamente non si tratta di un elogio fatto a una vecchia signora.

A volte le persone usano questo aggettivo per descriversi sé stesse. Per esempio, in [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=pAOMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT114&lpg=PT114&dq=%22soy+muy+mani%C3%A1tico+con+la+comida%22&source=bl&ots=0Sc1Fs_lOP&sig=ACfU3U2wWm-paspfcuIV3MLaJwY10zO6Tg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL6caUq8PqAhWmyoUKHXfNB5MQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22soy%20muy%20mani%C3%A1tico%20con%20la%20comida%22&f=false), una persona con sindrome di Asperger dice di sé stessa

> Soy muy maniático con la comida

che significa che questa persona ha molte fissazioni riguardo al mangiare e non si contenta con qualsiasi cosa.

O qualcuno potrebbe dire di sé stesso

> Soy un maniático del orden y  la limpieza

o di un'altra persona

> Es un maniático del orden y la limpieza

cosa che significa che si tratta di persone terribilmente esigenti riguardo all'ordine e la pulizia.

Quale aggettivo o espressione (o espressioni) potrei utilizzare in italiano per qualificare qualcuno che si atteggia in questi modi?

Comment: Mi viene in mente picchiatello ma non so se è del tutto azzeccato

Comment: ***maniático*** 
\manjátiko\ [adj/sm] maniaco, ***fissato***. 
 |  ésa es una maniática, no le hagas caso: quella è una fissata, non darle retta. https://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Spagnolo-Italiano/parola/M/manitico.aspx?query=mani%C3%A1tico

Comment: @Hachi:  Tendo a non guardare molto i dizionari bilingui che sono in rete perché, secondo la mia esperienza, molto spesso riportano traduzioni piuttosto cattive. Può darsi che in questo caso l'aggettivo "fissato" sia una buona opzione, però io veramente non lo so ed è per questo che ho bisogno di una vostra risposta. Potrei dire, per esempio, "mio amico è un fissato dell'ordine e la pulizia" o "è fissato con l'ordine e la pulizia" o qualcosa di questo genere per esprimere che si tratta di una persona terribilmente esigente con l'ordine e la pulizia?

Comment: Sì, entrambe le frasi sono corrette. Fissato è sia un sostantivo che un aggettivo. Penso che la traduzione sia buona.

Comment: @Hachi: E potrei anche dire "È una vecchia fissata"? Se si tratta di una buona traduzione, si dovrebbe scrivere come risposta.

Comment: Una vecchia (signora) fissata (con le pulizie).

Comment: @Hachi: Potresti scriverlo in una risposta, per favore?

Comment: Si può anche dire "avere la mania per ..." o "essere maniaco di ...", "avere la fissa di ...", "essere fissati con ..."; inoltre "essere fanatici di/per ..."

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica - Potresti scriverlo come risposta per favore?

Comment: @Hachi fatto; se ritieni, integra/migliora pure il testo.

Answer (score 2):

Raccolgo anche alcuni commenti per fare questa risposta.

Hachi riporta https://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Spagnolo-Italiano/parola/M/manitico.aspx?query=mani%C3%A1tico
che indica "maniático" come maniaco, fissato; "ésa es una maniática, no le hagas caso" diventa "quella è una fissata, non darle retta";
ritengo che sia una traduzione più che accettabile. La parola si può usare in modo generico,
quindi dire "quello è fissato" senza specificare altro, oppure completare con, per esempio:

> Essere fissati con la pulizia
> E' una fissata della pulizia
> E' una fissata per la pulizia

"Fissata" è legata a "fissa", "idea fissa", "fissazione", un interesse maniacale/esagerato. Altre
forme che esprimono concetti simili sono:

> avere la fissa di/del ...
> essere fissati con ...

...e inoltre si può usare mania e fanatismo:

> avere la mania per ...
> essere maniaco di/del ...
> essere fanatici di/per ...

Probabilmente esistono ulteriori modi di dire.

Infine, Riccardo de Contardi indica "picchiatello" che ha un senso un po' diverso ma in certi contesti si può sovrapporre. "Picchiatello" sarebbe bonariamente "picchiato in testa" e, avendo subito danni, il "picchiatello" mostra comportamenti o ragionamenti un po' deviati. "Toccatello" (toccato in testa) è una parola simile.